# Posting a collection/array of data/objects in a regular HTTP POST

Tags: http, jpa, spring-mvc

I have a `@OneToMany` JPA association with an instance of `Curriculum` having several instances of `WorkExperience`.

The issue I have is that I want to be able to persist **one** Curriculum together with **several** WorkExperiences in a **single** entity manager `persist/save` call.

I am not sure how to glue **several instances** of WorkExperiences coming from a regular HTTP POST of a  html form to a java **collection/set in the Spring MVC model attribute**...

First of all, is this possible at all? If so is it a good idea and **what kind of html** can post collections/arrays of data in a regular HTTP POST?

The  `Curriculum` JPA entity:

```
@Entity
public class Curriculum {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    private Set<WorkExperience> workExperiences;
    ...
```

The `WorkExperience` JPA entity:

```
@Entity
public class WorkExperience {
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Spring MVC supports sending Lists/Maps as form values.  The way that works is by subscripting the value.  For a List, you use the list number, like

```
<form:input path="myVal[1].property" />
```

And for a Map you use the map key like

```
<form:input path="myVal[key].property' />
```

This is assumming your Model Attribute has a List/Map of said item.  I would recommend using a DTO and translating to your Entity.  It may be overkill, but I have a problem with allowing the View to manipulate my Entity objects directly.

Also to note: You will have to do some View-side coding to dynamically add/remove items on the form.  This can be a real pain, as deletes don't work like you would imagine.  Spring MVC has the ability to add to a List/Map, alter the items in a List/Map, but I haven't found a way to remove items from a map directly.  I usually handle removes by adding a "remove" boolean flag into my DTOs, then tracking removals by simply adding a form:hidden element for that item in the List/Map, and clean the List/Map on the server-side when I get it.

Once you get all your Entities on the Server-side, then you have to store them.  If you want this to be more auto-magic, simply set an annotaion on your parent Entity like

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

There are several [CascadeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html)s available, so pick the one that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot CodeChimp!! It also seems that Thymeleaf supports the same syntax i.e. `${personsArray[0].name}` as per the documentation.

Comment: The curlies are standard EL (Expression Language).  I believe it's part of Servlet 2.5 (maybe 3.0)